# Calling properties using "Self" keyword and One-To-Many Relationships in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I'm new to Django, and having some trouble understanding how the `self` keyword works, compared to `this` in JS or C#.  I've been working through the [Django REST API tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/), and now am trying to add a second Model class.  I'd like to have a one-to-many relationship between each `Snippet` and `SubSnippets`, but would like to have my `SubSnippets` inherit the language and style properties of the parent `Snippet` so that I can use them in the `formatter` for each `SubSnippet`.  Here's the code I've added to `models.py`:

```
class SubSnip(models.Model):
    snippet = models.ForeignKey(Snippet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='sub-snippets', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    highlighted = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['snippet', 'created']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        lexer = get_lexer_by_name(self.snippet.language)
        linenos = 'table' if self.linenos else False
        options = {'title': self.title} if self.title else {'snippet title': self.snippet.title}
        formatter = HtmlFormatter(style=self.snippet.style, linenos=linenos,
                                full=True, **options)
        self.highlighted = highlight(self.code, lexer, formatter)
```

The problem is that `self.snippet.language` doesn't seem to be calling the actual Snippet class, because I'm getting an error that says "Instance of ForeignKey has no 'language' member." Same with `self.snippet.title` and `self.snippet.style`.

I find the convention of putting all Models in a single file a little strange, and I'm wondering if, from the compiler POV, that is why I can't access the properties of the Snippet class.  Or is it something else about how Models work in Django/Python?  I'd love to get a deeper understanding of what's happening here!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few questions here so I'll address one at a time.

As for your model structure, you can do something like this:

Keep in mind - in python, when we pass an object to a class declaration, that class will inherit the objects properties, attributes, and methods.

```
# Snippet inherits the default django model:
class Snippet(models.Model):

    # fields:
    title = models.ChardField(...)
    ...

    # this simple method returns the title:
    def get_title(self): 
        return self.title

# SubSnippet inherits the Snippet class:
class SubSnippet(Snippet):

   # fields:
   snippet = models.ForeignKey('Snippet', ...)
   ...
```

Now we can instantiate some instances like so:

```
# create a snippet:
snippet = Snippet.objects.create(
    title='I am the parent'
)

# create a subsnippet, and assign the above snippet as its 'parent':
subsnippet = SubSnippet.objects.create(
    title='I am the child', 
    snippet=snippet
)

# accessing fields:
print(subsnippet.title) # prints 'I am the child'
print(subsnippet.snippet.title) # prints 'I am the parent'
print(snippet.title) # prints 'I am the parent'

# using methods:
print(snippet.get_title()) # prints 'I am the parent'
print(subsnippet.get_title()) # prints 'I am the child'
```